# Get event when user clicks away from current element or children

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.5

Okay, I have tried to use a popup to get this to work but there are a ton of reasons why that doesn't appear to be a route I want to take...especially because I've spent the last two hours trying to get it to work and I've deemed it unholier than all hell (this is despite the fact that I have popups in other places in the app that work just fine, but I digress...)

Basically I need only one piece of functionality that doesn't appear to be standard out of the box in WPF...I have to determine when someone clicks on something OTHER than a known UI element (I.E. they click away from something to close it...much like a popup set to StaysOpen = false)

From what I have gathered this is quite an arduous task and I can't seem to find a straight answer on the best way to do this...any ideas SO?

**EDIT:**

One of the commenters wanted me to post some sample code and re-reading through my question I really don't want to post something that is unrelated (the XY problem). I am posting this question for two reasons:

1. The onmouseleave event gets fired as soon as the popup opens.  This means that if the popup is set to 'StaysOpen="False"' that the popup appears and immediately disappears no matter what.  I believe wholeheartedly that this will not be an issue if I create a component that appears using the Visibility attribute to appear and disappear rather than placing it in a popup.  The **only** reason I considered the popup component was because of it's StaysOpen=False functionality, not because it needs to float above everything else
2. The popup itself feels *quite* hacky, especially because it needs to fit inside of a parent component in the visual tree.  As you can see from the code below, I have gotten the popup to fit inside of it's parent...but I really don't like binding a component's width and height to another component's actual width and height.  This is the second reason I would like to avoid using a popup.

As a result, while this question could be 'how can I get the popup to work', the original question still stands:  "How can I listen for a on click **away** event?" I would like to create a component that fits in the visual tree logically, and behaves as the following:

1. On hover over a component, appear
2. On leave a component disappear
3. On click on a component persist appearing
4. On click away from a component or itself close

I have all of the above handled except for on click away

Comment: Did I understand correctly, you have `Popup`, it closes on click outside the `Popup` (with established `StaysOpen="False"`) and 1: it is closed, 2: not closed. If it is closed, it does not suit you or not? What is the particular behavior of the `Popup` you want?

Comment: Have you tried using VisualTreeHelper? It is very useful to walk up or down the visual tree and find elements on the way.

Comment: @anatoliynikolaev  No, the functionality works when I click the popup and then click away...the problem is I need it to open when one hovers over the item and then close whem they leave it -as well as- the click functionality to persist it...when they hover over the item the popup opens and immediately closes no matter what unless staysopen is true, which negates the rest

Comment: Please, could you show your code to understand the essence of your implementation? (Which element, where the popup, on which event, etc.)

Comment: Sure thing, I just need to get to a computer (Im on my phone at the moment)

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev I edited my question to elaborate...I really don't want to get into how to get the popup to work moreso than to answer the original question of how to handle a click away from an element

Comment: I understand, you need behavior such as `ToolTip`? I think 1,2,4 points they already supported.

Comment: hmmm, interesting approach but it suffers from the same issues of popup in that it doesn't really nest itself into the visual tree in a different location from the initial host element...basically there is a pane on the left of the window that hosts the the popable (if you will) control.  In the pane on the right is a list of ui elements which I want to preview on the left by hovering over them until I find an element which I want to persist (which would persist via a click)

Comment: Perhaps, I ve done something like this before. I had a panel with functions (displayed as icons), add, edit, delete. The icons have been `ToggleButton` at `IsChecked="True"` show up in the form of a `Border` with the function of closing (X button), specifically did not make it is not done by `Popup`. This `Border` can also be moved around the screen. In the open box doing certain actions, wanted to hide, hit the `X` button. If you want to hide in the other events, I think we can add the appropriate event handlers. If you are interested, I can later show your example.

Comment: I think it's a good alternative to put a close button on the area that 'pops up' but ultimately it should not be a requirement to get this funcionality...this isn't really a question of how I can get similar functionality, this is a question of how to handle a click event outside of the current element

Comment: Okay. You have a panel on the left. In it you want to do some action, showing another parallel with the panel of controls. Once you clicks on an item from the parallel panel, and `Popap`-panel on the left is hiding. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but the question is not at all related to popups...I want to handle a click away from an element in WPF, that's really the ultimate question here...I don't want to do so through trickery of the UI, I want to create a component that can detect when someone clicks away from it

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just confused with popups, when the question of the event.

Comment: When you say you use `StaysOpen`, you really meant that you wanted to use `IsOpen` right? Because `IsOpen` persists, when you set it manually, as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3117453/1466627)

Comment: yes, isopen persists...however, staysopen allows it to close when you click away from it, which is the behavior I am trying to recreate...regardless, as before, this isn't a question on popup controls, it's about handling a click event away from a control lol

Answer (score 1):

How about the [UIElement.LostFocus-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596673%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?appid=dev10idef1&l=de-de&k=k%28system.windows.uielement.lostfocus%29;k%28targetframeworkmoniker-%22.netframework,version=v4.0%22%29;k%28devlang-csharp%29&rd=true)? That seems to be the one you need.

Comment: I've checked this route out quite a bit actually and it doesn't quite behave correctly for what I want...mostly because it fires a lot of the time when you really don't want it to and you have to then re-open the 'popup' component that I'm trying to setup

Comment: That's because the event is bubbling up from the child elements. To handle that, you could f.e. check if the `sender` is actually the element you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, you can be useful routed events. There are two types of events: Bubbling, Direct and Tunneling. Attention should be paid to `Bubbling` and `Tunneling`. Bubbling events rises up the logical tree and tunneling down. Below is a diagram from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx):

[image]

So that event up / down the tree, it should be set on each control. Usually, the demonstration bubbling events, apply this example:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="DemoRoutedEvents.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" MouseUp="somethingClicked">

    <Grid MouseUp="somethingClicked">
        <StackPanel MouseUp="somethingClicked" Margin="0,0,10,0">
            <Label x:Name="btnClickMe" Content="Click Me!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="101,22,0,0" MouseUp="somethingClicked"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkhandle" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="241,28,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.588,1.188"/>
            <ListBox x:Name="lstEvents" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="604" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="416" Margin="29,66,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>    
</Window>
```

`Code behind`

```
public int eventCounter = 0;

private void somethingClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    eventCounter++;

    String message = "#" + eventCounter.ToString() + ":\r\n" +
            " Sender: " + sender.ToString() + ":\r\n" +
            " Source: " + e.Source + ":\r\n" +
            " Original Source: " + e.OriginalSource;

    lstEvents.Items.Add(message);
    e.Handled = (bool)chkhandle.IsChecked;

    if (e.Handled)
        lstEvents.Items.Add("Completed");

}
```

`Output`

[image]

I tried to optimize this process for multiple panels and components. I have created a attached dependency property `IsDebugEvent`, which is in the class of `EventBehaviours`. The principle is simple, we take an event handler and set it for all elements of the type `Control` (almost all the UIElements it inherits). For panels such as a Grid, StackPanel, WrapPanel, etc, `Panel` is the base class.

In the handler, we find `ListBox` and display the name of the panel s the element that caused the event, just for test. The example uses the event `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` (tunneling), because the first fires is an event at the `Button.Click`, and when it works, it conflicts with the event `MouseUp`. Quote from [here](http://wpf.2000things.com/2012/10/04/661-buttonbase-click-event-vs-mouse-click-events/):

> ButtonBase inherits from UIElement, a Button will also have access to all of the mouse button events defined for UIElement. Because the Button does something in response to button presses, it swallows the bubbling events (e.g. MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseDown). You can still detect these lower level button press events by adding handlers for the tunneling events (e.g. PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and PreviewMouseDown).

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="AwayEventHelp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AwayEventHelp"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="525"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">        

    <Grid>                
        <CheckBox Name="DebugCheckBox" Width="100" Height="30" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Content="Debug event" IsChecked="False" 
              Checked="DebugCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="DebugCheckBox_Unchecked" />

        <StackPanel Name="LeftStackPanel" Width="150" local:EventBehaviours.IsDebugEvent="False"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="BlanchedAlmond">

            <Button Name="LeftButton1" Height="30" Content="LeftButton1" />
            <Button Name="LeftButton2" Height="30" Content="LeftButton2" />
            <Button Name="LeftButton3" Height="30" Content="LeftButton3" />

            <Label Name="JustLabelLeft" Content="JustLabelLeft" Background="Azure" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Name="RightStackPanel" Width="150" local:EventBehaviours.IsDebugEvent="False"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Azure">

            <Button Name="RightButton1" Height="30" Content="RightButton1" />
            <Button Name="RightButton2" Height="30" Content="RightButton2" />
            <Button Name="RightButton3" Height="30" Content="RightButton3" />

            <Label Name="JustLabelRight" Content="JustLabelRight" Background="BlanchedAlmond" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid Name="GridPanel" Width="100" Height="100" local:EventBehaviours.IsDebugEvent="False"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="CadetBlue">

            <Label Name="LabelInGrid" Width="100" Height="50" Content="LabelInGrid" Background="AliceBlue" />
        </Grid>

        <ListBox Name="EventOutput" Width="180" Height="180" Background="AliceBlue" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DebugCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventBehaviours.SetIsDebugEvent(LeftStackPanel, true);
        EventBehaviours.SetIsDebugEvent(RightStackPanel, true);
        EventBehaviours.SetIsDebugEvent(GridPanel, true);
    }

    private void DebugCheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventBehaviours.SetIsDebugEvent(LeftStackPanel, false);
        EventBehaviours.SetIsDebugEvent(RightStackPanel, false);
        EventBehaviours.SetIsDebugEvent(GridPanel, false);
    }
}

public class EventBehaviours : DependencyObject
{
    #region IsDebugEvent declaration

    public static void SetIsDebugEvent(DependencyObject target, bool value)
    {
        target.SetValue(IsDebugEventProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsDebugEvent(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (bool)DepObject.GetValue(IsDebugEventProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDebugEventProperty =
                                              DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDebugEvent",
                                              typeof(bool),
                                              typeof(EventBehaviours),
                                              new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsDebugEvent));

    #endregion

    private static void OnIsDebugEvent(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Panel MyPanel = sender as Panel;            

        if (e.NewValue is bool && ((bool)e.NewValue == true))
        {
            MyPanel.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MyControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);

            if (MyPanel.Children.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (Control MyControl in MyPanel.Children)
                {
                    MyControl.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MyControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Control MyControl in MyPanel.Children)
            {
                MyControl.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= new MouseButtonEventHandler(MyControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);
            }

            MyPanel.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= new MouseButtonEventHandler(MyControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Main handler of PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event
    /// </summary>
    private static void MyControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        string OutInfo = string.Empty;

        if (sender.GetType() == typeof(StackPanel))
        {
            StackPanel MyStackPanel = sender as StackPanel;
            Grid MyGrid = MyStackPanel.Parent as Grid;

            OutInfo = "PanelName: " + MyStackPanel.Name;
            OutInfoInListBox(MyGrid, OutInfo);
        }
        else if (sender.GetType() == typeof(Grid))
        {
            Grid MyGrid = sender as Grid;
            Grid MyMainGrid = MyGrid.Parent as Grid;

            OutInfo = "PanelName: " + MyGrid.Name;
            OutInfoInListBox(MyMainGrid, OutInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            Control MyControl = sender as Control;
            Panel MyStackPanel = MyControl.Parent as Panel;
            Grid MyGrid = MyStackPanel.Parent as Grid;

            OutInfo = "ControlName: " + MyControl.Name;
            OutInfoInListBox(MyGrid, OutInfo);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get ListBox and insert some info
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ParentGrid">Panel, where locate ListBox</param>
    /// <param name="info">Just string</param>
    private static void OutInfoInListBox(Grid ParentGrid, string info) 
    {
        ListBox MyEventOutput = ParentGrid.FindName("EventOutput") as ListBox;
        MyEventOutput.Items.Add(info);
    }
}
```

`Output`

[image]

By clicking on the `CheckBox`, set a dependency property *`IsDebugEvent`* in `True`, subject thus causing `OnIsDebugEvent`, where we set the handlers. If you deselect the `CheckBox` in, then all event handlers deleted.

To set the events immediately on startup, you need to make sure that all the items on the successfully booted. This can be done in the event [`ContentRendered`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.contentrendered%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of `Window`.

Comment: Very interesting, I'm gonna spend some time with this tonight when I have a little more time...I will mark as an answer once I do so

Comment: @Robert Petz: You have no problems with my example? Maybe necessary need to explain something?

Comment: @Anatoly Nikolaev:  Haven't had a chance to take a look at this yet, I'm on the bubble with a massive project getting released...I'll let you know once I get a few minutes to check this out

Comment: @Robert Petz: Few minutes dragged on a long time :). Was it useful to you my example? If you have questions, please ask.